# Bootstrap modal opens after double click rather open at first click in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am working in an eCommerce application ,In this I have cart icon .What I want to do is when I click on the cart icon I want to show a modal screen with the user selected product data .

But in my case for the first time  after page loads modal screen opens after double click,afterwards it opens with the single click .

icon :

```
<i class="fas fa-cart-plus fa-flip-horizontal text-primary" (click)="get_My_Cart($event)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="font-size:25px;cursor: pointer;"></i>
```

Modal :

```
<div *ngIf="mycart && mycart.length" class="modal fade modalstyle" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header headerHeight text-white " style="background:rgb(0, 0, 0);font-weight:bold">
        <h6 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">My Cart Items</h6>
        <button #closeModalBtn type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div *ngFor="let products of mycart;let i =index;">
          <div class="container col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4 paddingforimage">
                <img [src]="products['ITEM_IMAGE_PATH']">
              </div>
              <div class="text-info col-sm-6">
                <span>
                  <h6>{{products?.TOTAL_QTY}} &times; {{products?.ITEM_PRICE}} &#8377;</h6>
                </span>
                <span>
                  <h6>{{products?.ITEM_DESC}}</h6>
                </span>
                <span>
                  <h6>{{products?.TOTAL_AMT}} &#8377;</h6>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-1 text-right">
                <button type="button" class="close closebtn" aria-label="Close" (click)="detele_My_Cart(products?.ITEM_CODE)">
                  <span aria-hidden="true" (click)="detele_My_Cart(products?.ITEM_CODE)">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class=" container row col-sm-12">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <strong>SHIPPING</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">0 &#8377;</div>
          <hr>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <strong>TOTAL</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">{{my_Cart_Total_Amount}} &#8377;</div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="container row col-sm-12" id="wrapper">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success buttonSize" data-dismiss="modal" routerLink="/cartsummary">
            <strong>CHECK OUT</strong>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component:

```
get_My_Cart($event) {

 this.publicIp.v4().then(ip => {
        this.CartdataService.get_My_Cart_Products(ip).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.mycart = data['Table']
                this.my_Cart_Total_Amount = data['Table1'][0]['TOTAL_AMOUNT']
            });
    });
}
```

Here in modal screen I have a validation ,Modal screen is open if data is bind in it otherwise it will not .(modal will not open if the cart is empty).

```
*ngIf="mycart && mycart.length"
```

If I remove this validation from the modal screen it works ,but it always opens (if there is no product in cart and user clicked on the cart icon it opens but I want to restrict it .)

can anyone tell me how to handle this issue ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow of code is not correct.

Anyway, I think, you're using `jQuery` & `Bootstrap.js`. **(Bad Idea)**

You can programmatically trigger the modal `using $('#exampleModal').modal('show')` once data comes from server.

```
declare var $ :any;

get_My_Cart($event) {
   this.publicIp.v4().then(ip => {
        this.CartdataService.get_My_Cart_Products(ip).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.mycart = data['Table']
                this.my_Cart_Total_Amount = data['Table1'][0]['TOTAL_AMOUNT']
                if(this.mycart && this.mycart.length)
                    $('#exampleModal').modal('show')
            });
    });
}
```

---

But there is a simple workaround in this case. Try to toggle `display` property of CSS instead of removing it from DOM using `*ngIf`.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{display: mycart && mycart.length ? 'block':'none'}" class="modal fade modalstyle">

</div>
```

Comment: got this error in console ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'none'

Comment: looking for your solution @RitwickDey

Comment: Sorry for late (this is my exam time).... anyway, there was a typo... `"display: mycart && mycart.length ? 'block':'none' "`.... btw, try of them. 1st one should work...

Comment: it is worked ,Can you please explain why it's not worked before and how it's worked now ?

Comment: For First : working fine but when I go to browser console there is an error like this "ERROR TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function"  @RitwickDey

Comment: For Second : not the app gets loaded in browser and console says "Uncaught Error: Quotes are not supported for evaluation!
        Statement:  mycart && mycart.length ? block:none"  @RitwickDey

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I made a mistake. This is like kind of object like syntax. I fixed the answer....`{display: mycart && mycart.length ? 'block':'none'}`

Comment: You said, first one is working. you're getting `ERROR TypeError: $(...).modal` for a signal time... right?

Comment: First one is working but it shows the "ERROR TypeError: $(...).modal" this error for each button click @@RitwickDey

Comment: strange!   Can you come to chat discussion of Stackoverflow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172207/discussion-between-ritwick-dey-and-nikson).

Comment: Please check the stackblitz url : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-uvakpv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts @RitwickDey

Comment: but in stackblitz I have given the same code I have in my project but it's working fine in stackblitz but not in my real project .for me it's open the modal after double at first time but in stackblitz opens with single click.

Note : double click need when the page is loaded first time after it opens with single click.

Comment: because in Stackblitz, you're fetching data in `ngOnInit()` life cycle hook.  do the same for your project @Nikson

Comment: Check out this. I edited your Stackblitz code.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-mxwwnn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Bro if I have the method inside the ngOnInit cart data will have only the data of pageload ,If I added new product that will not get updated in cart coz noOnInit will get updated when I refresh it @RitwickDey

Comment: Yep! checkout the my code. It is working. & it's not in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: The same code I have applied in my real project ,it is not working ,opens with double click only @RitwickDey

Comment: you said, the $('#...').modal is undefined.. I don't why it is..! but check on `Stackblitz`, it's not undefined.